# Servlets not found in AWS

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

1. I have a GWT dynamic web project and I generate the .war file
2. I test it on a Tomcat in localhost, works fine.
3. I upload it to Amazon Web Services, Elastic Beanstalk running an Apache Tomcat 6
4. When I run the deployed version in AWS, it cant find the servlets, like they don't exist
5. Tried it with a new GWT project, still wont work: "Servlet not found"

I'm kind of stuck. I'm not sure if this is a GWT issue or if I'm doing something wrong with AWS-Elastic Beanstalk.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution after doing a lot testing and stuff:

A Tomcat 6 is whats running under the hood in elastic beanstalk and by default, when you upload a XYZ.war file to a Tomcat, the context-url is (context-root)/XYZ. 
I was uploading a war named MyWebProject.war, so to Tomcat, it is deployed on (context-root)/XYZ but to elastic beanstalk, it is deployed to YOUR_URL.elasticbeanstalk.com

This obiously causes the web.xml to get confused in a really weird way, so tu summarize:

**Rename you XYZ.war to ROOT.war and upload it. That should fix the problem.**